# Value not persisting on Submit with validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, submit, http-post

I'm using MVC3 .NET4.0 (VB), and I'm seeing some strange behavior on a simple View. It's a Create view that is set up as:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of MyProject.MyTable)
```

The controller is pretty straightforward. It accepts the ID of the parent record to which this record is being added:

```
Function Create(parent As Integer) As ActionResult
    Return View(New MyTable With {.parent_id = parent})
End Function
```

The View also accepts a date among other things, but it boils down to this:

```
<% Using Html.BeginForm()%>
<%=Html.ValidationSummary(True)%>
<%=Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.parent_id)%>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.start_date)%>
<%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.start_date, "*")%>
<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Save</button>
<% End Using%>
```

I'm testing the handling of date errors, so right now my post controller is just checking for errors and not doing much else:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Create(model As MyTable) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    Else
        Return View(model)
    End If
End Function
```

When I first load the view, I see the parent ID displayed on the form. If I put a bad date into the start date field and hit Submit, the form comes back with the invalid value highlighted, but the parent ID = 0. If I break the code in the post, I can see that "model" doesn't have the parent ID set. This obviously causes all kinds of problems, because I've essentially lost who the parent is. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Per Darin's suggestion I changed DisplayFor to HiddenFor and didn't see any difference. So then I tried TextBoxFor and got stranger results. I still don't see the parent ID in the post function, but the value persists in the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are not including the `parent_id` as hidden field in your form. Inside your form you have a single input element which corresponds to the `start_date` field, so that's all that you can hope to get in your POST action.

So:

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.parent_id) %>
```

The `DisplayFor` that you used only displays the value, it doesn't emit any input field to transport this value to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: I thought DisplayFor did the same thing, but I tried HiddenFor and got the same results - parent ID = 0 in the post function.

Comment: @gfrizzle, no DisplayFor only generates a label. How does your HTML look like? Look at the source. Normally you should see `<input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value="123" />`. It's that value that you will get back in your POST action.

Comment: The HiddenFor does indeed persist the ID value, but I think my ultimate problem is with the parent itself. These tables are in a LINQ to SQL class, meaning there is an object named "Parent" in addition to the "parent_id" field. When I drill into the ModelState, I can see key/value pairs for "parent_id" and "start_date" as I would expect, but also one for "Parent", and it appears to be trying to set "Parent" to a string value equivalent to the parent_id, i.e. it's trying to do 'Parent = "2"', and the ModelState is invalid as a result. Am I not setting up the get controller in the first place?

Comment: @gfrizzle, how does your route definition look like? Have you changed the default routes? How does the `action` attribute of the `<form>` look like in the generated HTML?

Comment: Ugh, I'm my own worst enemy sometimes. It looks like the code was having a problem with the fact that I was using the variable "parent" to pass the ID in, while there is also a "Parent" object on MyTable. Once I changed the variable to "parentId", everything flowed through correctly (with the HiddenFor of course). Thanks for all your help.